# Bloc Library Null

Tags: flutter, dart

В homepage в appbar отображаю иконки авторизованного и не авторизованного юсера. Если войти, иконка профиля отображается , но выводит ошибку A build function returned null.  Если нажать на профиль, инфо отображается но снова выводит эту же ошибку. Вернувшись назад вместо иконок красный блок с ошибкой.
Почему возвращает null?
main:

```
class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc(
              authService: AuthService())
            ..add(
              AppStart(),
            ),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

homepage:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>( 
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is Authenticated) {
                user = state.user;
              } else if (state is UnAuthenticated) {
                return logIn(context);
              }
              else {
               return user == null ? Container() : profileIcon(context); // !!!
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

bloc

```
@override
Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
  if (event is AppStart) {
    try {
      final user = await AuthService.getCurrentUser();
      yield Authenticated(user: user);
    } catch (e) {
      yield UnAuthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

profileIcon:

```
Widget profileIcon(context) {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      FlatButton.icon(
        icon: Icon(
        label: Text(
          'Профиль',
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfile()));
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: `AuthBloc(authService: AuthService())..add(AppStart(),),` странная конструкция... И приложите код с `profileIcon(context)`, вы туда передаете только `context`, а как-же `state`?

Comment: Добавил код иконки. При запуске приложения, запускается event `..add(AppStart())` и определяется состояние авторизован или нет. Если можно на счет странности, объясните.  Для чего передавать `state`?

Comment: Добавил в `BlocBuilder` else return Container(), теперь ошибки с возвращением Null нет, но перейдя на страницу профиля и вернувшись назад, возвращает Container(), как я понял блок не срабатывает. Использую кнопку назад самого телефона для возврата, может это имеет значение?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете `builder` (а по сути это обычный метод `build`) вы обязаны возвращать виджет.

У вас до этого была конструкция такая:

```
builder: (context, state) {
  if (state is Authenticated) {
    return profileIcon(context);
  } else if (state is UnAuthenticated) {
    return logIn(context);
  }
},
```

То есть, вы не оброботали все возможные варианты выхода из этого `builder`.
После вы изменили его на такой:

```
builder: (context, state) {
  if (state is Authenticated) {
    return profileIcon(context);
  } else if (state is UnAuthenticated) {
    return logIn(context);
  }
  else {
    return Container()
  }
},
```

Здесь вы добавили выход из `builder`.

---

А теперь почему `BLoC`, не срабатывает. Приходящий `state` не является `Authenticated` или `UnAuthenticated`, а нечто другим, это вы сам и показали когда добавили проверку с `Container()`.

И второе замечание, вы не используете приходящий `state`, не извлекаете из него данные, это не `event` чтобы распознать откуда пришло событие, это состояние обработанного `event` (то есть, оно должно перестраивать ui основываясь на данных из `state`).

---

Такая конструкция проверки:

```
if (...) {...}
else if (...) {...}
```

Эквивалентно такой:

```
if (...) {...}
if (...) {...}
```

Как вы можете понять, не всегда можно попасть в эти две проверки...

---

Как должно быть по идее.

homepage:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>( 
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is Authenticated) {
                profileIcon(context, state); // Передаем состояние
              } else if (state is UnAuthenticated) {
                return logIn(context);
              }
              else {
               // Возможно мы не попадаем в проверки, по этому узнаем какой тип к нам пришел.
               print(state.runtimeType);
               // И показываем заглушку в виде контейнера
               return Container();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

profileIcon:

```
Widget profileIcon(context, state) {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      FlatButton.icon(
        icon: Icon(...),
        label: Text('Профиль'),
        onPressed: () async {
          // Также передаем user в UserProfile, ведь это данные о User...
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfile(state.user)));
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Исправил код, если я вас правильно понял.

Comment: @AndreyKhan добавил код, попробуйте запустить его и посмотреть какой тип придет в консоль.

Comment: при запуске выводит AuthState, после как перехожу в профиль LoadUserData. Для вывода инфо юсера использую другой ивент с состояниями.

Comment: проблема в том что разные ивенты и состояния, при переходе в профиль срабатывал event LoadUserData далее через BlocBuilder выводил данные. Сейчас сделал все в одном и передал в UserProfile данные от state работает. Но насколько это правильно делать все через один event и state?

Comment: @AndreyKhan по моему мнению связанная логика должна обрабатываться в одно месте. Я не адепт данной архитектуры и не смогу вам точно сказать. Но просматривая примеры, мне кажется это правильный подход.
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/ru/flutterfirebaselogintutorial?id=flutter-firebase-login